# How to use references of C# 9 source code generator in unit tests?

Tags: c#, roslyn, c#-9.0, sourcegenerators

I have a C# 9.0 source code generator that references a class library that contains an attribute that is used to identify the classes to process. I am now writing unit tests as described [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/source-generators.cookbook.md):

```
        Compilation inputCompilation = CreateCompilation(@"
        using Dependncy;
        namespace MyCode
        {
            [Marker]
            public partial class SimpleObject
            {
                [PropertyMarker(0)]
                public int Test{get;set;}
            }
        }
        ");

        var generator = new MyCodeGen();

        // Create the driver that will control the generation, passing in our generator
        GeneratorDriver driver = CSharpGeneratorDriver.Create(generator);

        // Run the generation pass
        // (Note: the generator driver itself is immutable, and all calls return an updated version of the driver that you should use for subsequent calls)
        driver = driver.RunGeneratorsAndUpdateCompilation(inputCompilation, out var outputCompilation, out var diagnostics);

        // We can now assert things about the resulting compilation:
        Assert.IsTrue(diagnostics.IsEmpty); // there were no diagnostics created by the generators
        Assert.IsTrue(outputCompilation.SyntaxTrees.Count() == 2); // we have two syntax trees, the original 'user' provided one, and the one added by the generator
        Assert.IsTrue(outputCompilation.GetDiagnostics().IsEmpty); // verify the compilation with the added source has no diagnostics

        // Or we can look at the results directly:
        GeneratorDriverRunResult runResult = driver.GetRunResult();
        // The runResult contains the combined results of all generators passed to the driver
        Assert.IsTrue(runResult.GeneratedTrees.Length == 1);
        Assert.IsTrue(runResult.Diagnostics.IsEmpty);

        // Or you can access the individual results on a by-generator basis
        GeneratorRunResult generatorResult = runResult.Results[0];
        Assert.IsTrue(generatorResult.Generator == generator);
        Assert.IsTrue(generatorResult.Diagnostics.IsEmpty);
        Assert.IsTrue(generatorResult.GeneratedSources.Length == 1);
        Assert.IsTrue(generatorResult.Exception is null);
```

`CreateCompilation` looks like this

```
private static Compilation CreateCompilation(string source)
        => CSharpCompilation.Create("compilation",
            new[] { CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(source) },
            new[] { MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Binder).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location), MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(MarkerAttribute).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location) },
            new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.ConsoleApplication));
```

However, the generator will not recognize the marker attribute (symbols are not equal). I guess, the issue is, that within the compilation, they are treated as from another assembly: One from the compilation within the UnitTest and the one that is references in the source code generator.

The source code generator obtains the symbol to compare with `compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName(typeof(MarkerAttribute).FullName)` but also references the containing assembly itself. I include the reference with `GetDependencyTargetPaths` as they do it in the official sample [csproj](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-sdk/blob/main/samples/CSharp/SourceGenerators/SourceGeneratorSamples/SourceGeneratorSamples.csproj).

Any idea how I have to create the compilation, so that the symbols are equal in the source generator?

### Edit 1

I just found out, that the `AttributeClass` seems to match the type (i.e. Names are equal), but its Kind Property returns `SymbolKind.ErrorType` while the one obtained by the source gen with `compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName(typeof(MarkerAttribute).FullName)` returns `SymbolKind.NamedType`. So that's probably why they don't match. However, I still have no idea why the symbols are resolved differently.